# Ejecutar script Python en segundo plano o como servicio

Tags: python

Buenas, he programado un HIDS (Sistema de detección de intrusos en un Host) el cual está en `fichero.py`, necesito ejecutar este `fichero.py` como servicio de WINDOWS o bien en segundo plano de forma permanente SIN QUE SE PUEDE ACCEDER AL CÓDIGO DE `fichero.py`.

Uso `Python 3.6` y he intentado crear un servicio de WINDOWS como indica aquí: http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/windows_services_in_python, sin embargo, parece ser que los `import` no me funcionan aún habiendo instalado los requerimientos, ya que creo que en `Python 3.6` el nombre de los `import` han cambiado y no logro hacerlo funcionar.

¿Alguna forma de poder ejecutar `fichero.py` de forma permanente en segundo plano sin que se pueda ver el código fuente de `fichero.py`?

Comment: Con este software Colmena Xsunfur suite puedes crear tu aplicación en un archivo ejecutable, además hace un proceso de ofuscación y reversión de código lo que resuelve tu problema más sin embargo es que ese proceso que protegido mediante una contraseña que tu le ingreses y si la olvidas pierdes tu código fuente..

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo lo estás haciendo?, ¿puedes mostrar tu código?

Answer (score 1):

Hola buen dia te anexo un ejemplo  de un servicio en python.
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2016-May/013705.html

```
import win32serviceutil, win32service
import win32event, win32api
import servicemanager
import time

import win32gui, win32gui_struct, win32con

class EventDemoService(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "PyServiceEventDemo"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Python Service Event Demo"
    _svc_description_ = "Demonstrates a Python service which takes 
    advantage of the extra notifications"
    def __init__(self, args):
         win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
         self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
         self.running = True
    def SvcStop(self):
         self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
         win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
         self.running = False
    def SvcDoRun(self):
         self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
         while self.running:
         servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("aservice - is alive and well")
         time.sleep(3)
def ctrlHandler(ctrlType):
    return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ctrlHandler, True)
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(EventDemoService)
```

Comment: Esto debería ser un comentario: "Hola buen dia te anexo un ejemplo de un servicio en python." , agrega el ejemplo a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

**Para ejecutar fichero.py como un servicio de windows puedes utilizar nssm** **en su versión estable 2.24**  [Descarga aqui https://nssm.cc/download](https://nssm.cc/download)

Descomprime el archivo y guardalo en una carpeta en disco local C: guarda ahí tambié el archivo fichero.py
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Abre una ventana cmd y posicionate en la carpeta con el comando cd
C:\ServicioPY\nssm-2.24\win64

Corre el siguiente comando

```
nssm install "NombredelServicio" "C:\Python310\python.exe" "C:\ServicioPY\fichero.py"
```

donde:
"C:\Python310\python.exe"  es la ruta donde se instaló python, puedes lcoalizarla abriendo una ventana nueva de cmd y corriendo `where python`

y "C:\ServicioPY\fichero.py" es la ruta de tu script

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después podrás visualizar en la ventana de servicios de windows tu servicio corriendo, puedes iniciarlo, detenerlo o pausarlo desde ahí.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score -1):

Lo primero tendras que crear un ejecutable, por ejemplo con http://www.pyinstaller.org y despues puedes crear el servicio con sc.exe create  binPath= "

Comment: Intenta redactar mejor tu Respuesta y dar mas información, como un link a algún tutorial, o escribe tu mismo como realizar los pasos en ésta misma respuesta. Saludos!