# Programador de tareas no ejecuta script Python

Tags: python, script, windows10

tengo un problema al ejecutar un script de python en el programador de tareas. Es un script que envía correos de outlook. Si marco la opción ejecutar cuando el usuario inició sesión como si no.no funciona no ejecuta, pero si marco solo cuando inicie sesión el usuario si ejecuta. Le marqué los privilegios elevados pero ni aún así funciona. También lo probé con un .bat y tampoco funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

**Puedes intentar correrlo como un servicio Automático en windows** en lugar de utilizar el programador de tareas

[Ejecutar script Python en segundo plano o como servicio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48670/ejecutar-script-python-en-segundo-plano-o-como-servicio/615361#615361)
En este link se indica como hacerlo.

Sin embargo si puedes subir tu script de python estaría excelente para poder dar una respuesta más acorde a lo que estás trabajando.

Comment: Cuando la respuesta ya esta en el sitio, se marca la pregunta como duplicada... no vamos a volver a escribir siempre lo mismo ;)